# Python subprocess package does not report errors from subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

On some machine, for the following piece of code

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT);
out, err = p.communicate()
```

This script would just hang at `p.communicate()` and does not return.

After I manually run the command, I finally see the error messages.

Why is this, and how should I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the error messages?  Do you have the same problem if you try a different command?  What is `cmd`?

Comment: your process seems not to terminate, and communicate() method just waits for it to happen, as it is documented. and not that the error code is undefined until subprocess terminates (returning this code to the OS and eventually to parent process)

Comment: so please define exactly what is the desired interaction scheme you are trying to achieve. Do you need to feed process with input data and capture output?... For instance, if you need only wait for termination and capture error code, the `subprocess.call()` will suffice.

Comment: @mgilson That is a script written by myself, reporting some basic numpy errors, like shapes don't align.

Comment: @spacediver But why wouldn't it terminate? It throws an unhandled exception already. I don't need to feed it with input, but I need to process its output.

Comment: @CodeNoob -- you haven't answered my question.  What happens if you try a different command (say `cmd='ls'`).  One thing that you may need to do is split command `cmd = shlex.split(cmd)`, but it's really hard to know without knowing what `cmd` actually is.

Comment: yep, if cmd contains your python script, then it does matter how you invoke the python interpreter to run it

Comment: I see that Popen does recieve not the string `cmd`, but the list of argument substrings, so you might need to pass `cmd.split()` instead of just `cmd`

Comment: @mgilson if I run any other command (like ls), it is fine. my cmd variable is really just a properly split python list, like ['./a.py', '-C', 'blah]. where a.py was written by myself.

Comment: @spacediver I invoke it like ['./a.py', '-C', 'blah]. Why does how I invoke the python interpreter matter?

Comment: try to invoke interpreter in most explicit manner possible, like this: `['/usr/bin/python', '/a.py', ...]` Thus you would isolate your invocation from shell/shebang settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your program never ends?

when you call communicate() it does different things under different os. But it always waits for the launched process to exit on its own eg. calls p.wait().
p.wait() terminates only if the rocess terminates.

Solutions:

- You could copy the source code of subprocess.Popen._communicate and alter it so it does not use wait() but time.sleep and some timeout
- You write your own code that reads stdout and stderr and stops if the program outputs too much stderr
- You change the main() function of the file that never ands this way

way

```
def main():
    ## here is you program code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import thread, sys, time
    _id = thread.start_new(main, ())
    time.sleep(1)
    t = time.time() + 100 # execute maximum 100 + 1 seconds
    while t > time.time() and _id in sys._current_frames():
        time.sleep(0.001)
```

If you want to look at the source of subprocess you can find it at `subprocess.__file__`.

Answer (score 0):

try `stderr = subprocess.PIPE` not `stderr = subprocess.STDOUT`